# "Not all fields were entered," when I submit a form. I am using PHP 7

Tags: php

I am new to PHP: I have searched over 20 answers and tried the various codings suggested without resolving the problem. My issue has obviously caused a problem in the past with other users because of the many times the question has been asked. The issue is that I get a return of "Not all fields were entered," when I submit a form. I am using PHP 7.

I know that I am connected to my MySQL database because I get a return of, "Connected to MySQL" when I submit the query - msqlconnect.php

Here is my code:

```
<?php
include_once 'functions.php';
$error = $user = $pass = "";

if ($_POST &&isset($_POST['user'], $_POST['pass'])) {
    $user = sanitizeString($_POST['user']);
    $pass = sanitizeString($_POST['pass']);


    if ($user == "" || $pass == "") {
        $error = "Not all fields were entered<br />";
    } else {
        $token = md5("$pass");

        $query = 'SELECT user,pass FROM password
              WHERE user='$user' AND pass=\'$token\'';

        if (mysql_num_rows(queryMysql($query)) == 0) {
            $error = "Username/Password invalid<br />";
        } else {
            $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
            $_SESSION['pass'] = $token;
            die("You are now logged in. Please
               <a href='xxxx_member.php?view=$user'>click here</a>.");
        }
    }
}

    echo <<<_END
    <form method='post' action='xxxx.php'>$error<br />
    E-Mail Address: <input type='text' maxlength='255' name='user'
value='$user' /><br /><br />
    Password:  <input type='password' maxlength='255' name='pass'
value='$pass' /><br />
    <br /><br />
    <input type='submit' value='Login' />
    </form>
    _END;
    ?>
```

It seems to me that the code is not getting beyond the first 'else' but I cannot work out why.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

As requested, here are the 'sanitize' functions:

```
    function sanitizeString($var)
    {
    $con = @mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');
    $user = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['user']);
    $psass = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['pass']);

    }

    function sanitizemysqli($var)
    {
    $var = mysqli_real_escape_string($var);
    $var = sanitizeString($var);
    return $var;
    }
```

Comment: You should also post the code of function `sanitizeString`

Comment: Warning : `mysql_num_rows()` and all `mysql_xx` functions were deprecated a long time ago and were removed since PHP7. You must not use them in your code for security reasons. See http://php.net/manual/intro.mysql.php

Comment: Crozet - Seen, understood and edited.

Comment: CBroe and Jack: Thank you:

Comment: @Hamish Please edit your *question* to include the sanitize function, not the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem appears because the function sanitizeString is not returning the correct string and is returning a empty string. That´s why you always see the same message.
I would debug those variables to see if they are filled or not. Something like this:

```
 <?php
    include_once 'functions.php';
    $error = $user = $pass = "";

    if ($_POST &&isset($_POST['user'], $_POST['pass'])) 

    {
$user = sanitizeString($_POST['user']);
$pass = sanitizeString($_POST['pass']);
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($user);
var_dump($pass);
die();


if ($user == "" || $pass == "")
{
    $error = "Not all fields were entered<br />";
}
else
{
    $token = md5("$pass");

    $query = "SELECT user,pass FROM password
              WHERE user='$user' AND pass='$token'";

    if (mysql_num_rows(queryMysql($query)) == 0)
    {
        $error = "Username/Password invalid<br />";
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
        $_SESSION['pass'] = $token;
        die("You are now logged in. Please
           <a href='xxxx_member.php?view=$user'>click here</a>.");
    }
}
    }



    echo <<<_END
    <form method='post' action='xxxx.php'>$error<br />
    E-Mail Address: <input type='text' maxlength='255' name='user'
value='$user' /><br /><br />
    Password:  <input type='password' maxlength='255' name='pass'
value='$pass' /><br />
    <br /><br />
    <input type='submit' value='Login' />
    </form>
    _END;
    ?>
```

With this you can check what is happening step by step.

Comment: I have tried another browser and it has returned:"array(2) { ["user"]=> string(6) "xxxxxx" ["pass"]=> string(3) "xxx" } NULL NULL". But I do not understand what it is telling me.

Comment: When is happening that thing? Try it independently to see what´s happening if not remove the Sanitizestring function

Comment: Paco: This is happening when I enter data into the 2 fields and click 'Submit'. The error above is returned.